# Exporting and Importing content using a JSON config

Tags: contentful

I am trying to export a space from contentful using the Export/import tool and the option config json file.

What is the file path where the config file should be?

Comment: As they say on their [docs page](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/tools/spacemanagement/) "You can import data from other systems into Contentful using our contentful-importer.rb gem." Also there is a tutorial available there.

Answer (score 1):

Contentful DevRel here. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

I assume you're referring to the `config.json` file mentioned [in the docs](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/tutorials/cli/import-and-export/). The config file is optional in case you don't want to pass the command-line options. The CLI options will do the job just fine.

If you want to go with this config file you choose the file path and can run the command with the path to your config as follows:

```
contentful space export --config example-config.json
```

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: Ah great thanks, I wasn't including the file path with the name of the config file.